# Django 1.3: Outbox empty during tests

Tags: django, django-testing

Maybe I don't understand how outbox works but from the documentation I understood that it just catches all outgoing mail during testing.

I created a new project with a new application and added the following code.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.mail import send_mail, outbox

class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def test_basic_addition(self):
        send_mail('Subject here', 
                  'Here is the message.', 
                  'from@example.com', 
                  ['to@example.com'], 
                  fail_silently=False)

        self.assertEqual( len( outbox ), 1 )
```

When I run python manage.py test app_name it gives an assertion error that 0 != 1. Am I doing something wrong?

**Update**

Well this is weird if I import django.core.mail and use mail.outbox it does work.

Tried to compare the direct import of outbox and mail.outbox and they both give different results

```
from django.core import mail
from django.core.mail import send_mail, outbox     
...
self.assertEqual(outbox, mail.outbox)
```

returns:

```
- []
+ [<django.core.mail.message.EmailMessage object at 0x1e1fd90>]
```

Maybe I've been working to long and missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Maybe I should actually read the documentation.

> The outbox attribute is a special attribute that is created only when the locmem e-mail backend is used. It doesn't normally exist as part of the django.core.mail module and you **can't import it directly**.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#email-services

Comment: They should probably make that fail fast for clarity. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: For other dummies like me that need it spelled out for them: DON'T use `from django.core.mail import outbox`. Instead, use `from django.core import mail` and in your test use `mail.outbox` instead of `outbox`.